# Improve PriorityQueue remove in Java API

Tags: java, heap, time-complexity, priority-queue

I have implemented a PriorityQueue (Max heap) using [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove(java.lang.Object)). Sometimes I need to remove an certain element from the queue, but the method `remove()` takes O(n) time, is there any way I can improve that to for example O(logn) using this API? Or do I need to implement my own PQ by scratch?

I've tried using a HashMap to store the index of each element, but I have no idea of how to remove an element from the PQ based by the index, is this possible?

I guess in that case the idea would be to:

- Find the element by index
- Shift it up in O(logn) time
- Extract the element in constant time

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't looked the API,but if I wanted a queue with fast removal I would use array based queues.

Comment: You should instead call PriorityQueue.poll(), which will have O(log(n)) time according to [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Comment: @hermit you mean a circular array? I think that us even more inefficient than a priority queue.

Comment: @CharlesSpencer PriorityQueue.poll() only removes the head, I need to remove elements based on some attribute or index..

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the other question doesn't relate to the Java API at all. And the link to the implementation in C# does not work.

Comment: A PQ isn't intended to support removal of arbitrary elements. Neither is a queue, for that matter.